# jQuery Click event not triggered in Chrome 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, onclick

My goal is to create a form completion with jQuery. Some ajax gets a list of teachers matching the letters inserted in a text field (input#saisie). This list is displayed in a select field (#list-results) dynamically created. It works fine with Firefox and IE but not with Chrome: select#list-results is created with teachers' list but the click event attached to each insider option element is not triggered. Therefore form is not filled.

My code is as follow :

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
           var counter = 0;

           $('input#saisie').keyup(
                function(event) {
                    if ((event.which == 8 || event.which == 46) && $('input#saisie').val().length == 0) {
                        $('#list-results').remove(); 
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                    if ($('input#saisie').val().length < 3) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        /* 'url': 'http://localhost:8000/ajax/search/', */
                        'url': 'http://enseignements-2014.ehess.fr/ajax/search/',
                        'type': 'GET',
                        'context': 'document.body',
                        'success': function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                           var l = document.location.href.split('/');
                           l.pop();
                           var location = l.join('/');
                           $($('form').get(0)).attr('action', location + '/');

                           $('#list-results').remove(); 
                           var select = $('<select id="list-results"></select>');
                           for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++) {
                                var option = $('<option>' + data[i]['prenom'] + ' ' + data[i]['nom'] + '</option>');
                                option.data('data', data[i]);
                                option.click(
                                    function(event) {
                                        $('input#id_prenom').val($(this).data('data')['prenom']);
                                        $('input#id_nom').val($(this).data('data')['nom']);
                                        SelectBox.move_all("id_qualites_to","id_qualites_from");
                                        SelectFilter.refresh_icons("id_qualites");
                                        $('select#id_qualites_from').val($(this).data('data')['qualites']);
                                        SelectBox.move("id_qualites_from","id_qualites_to");
                                        SelectFilter.refresh_icons("id_qualites");
                                        $('input#id_autre_qualite').val($(this).data('data')['autre_qualite']);
                                        $('input#id_retraite').val($(this).data('data')['retraite']);
                                        if ($(this).data('data')['hdr'] == false) {
                                            $('input#id_hdr').attr('checked', false);
                                        }
                                        if ($(this).data('data')['retraite'] == false) {
                                            $('input#id_retraite').attr('checked', false);
                                        }
                                        if ($(this).data('data')['hdr'] == true) {
                                            $('input#id_hdr').attr('checked', true);
                                        }
                                        if ($(this).data('data')['retraite'] == true) {
                                            $('input#id_retraite').attr('checked', true);
                                        }
                                        $('input#id_intitule').val($(this).data('data')['intitule']);
                                    }
                                );
                                select.append(option);
                           }

                           $('div#ajax-results').append(select);
                        },
                        'error': function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            $('p#ajax-error').text('Une erreur est survenue lors de votre requête. Insérez manuellement l\'enseignant.');
                        },
                        'data': 'search=' + $('input#saisie').val()
                    });  
            }
        );
    }
);
```

If a put a

```
$('#list-results>option')[0].click()
```

in the Chrome's console it works fine. But do not if I use my mouse.
I don't know how to delegate event from select's div parent element since option are filled with ajax data.

Any idea ?

Thx a lot

Frédéric

Comment: Do you mean Chrome 33? Nobody uses Chrome 3.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ but be aware, chrome doesn't support any event bound to option, bound event to SELECT and better use here onchange i guess

Comment: `$('#list-results>option:first').change()`. Maybe change() is a correct approach since it is a selectbox, no?

Comment: I would bind a change event handler to the select instead of attaching a click on every option, since options do not trigger click event `:/`